# Which technique for database design is better for performance?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I need to create a Django PostgreSQL Database with a field in multiple tables to use it like a filter for the users, but I don't know what technique to use for performance.

I can create a table with the field and make a foreign key for every table.

```
class Tablefilter(models.Model):
    filter_field = models.Field()

class Tablefilted(models.Model):
    table_filter = models.ForeignKey(Tablefilter)
```

Or in my models just create a extend for that field in every model.

```
class Tablefilter(models.Model):
    filter_field = models.Field()

class Tablefilted(Tablefilter):
    field = models.Field()
```

Comment: In the first method you have a one-to-many relationship. With the second one (inherirance) you have a implicit one-to-one relationship. They yield different results in database level. Please, be more specific to your problem, to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some elaboration.
However, filtering is better to be done through the views, not via the models. So basically have some parameters on the frontend supplied to our views, and use Django's filter by inbuilt function.